# Ошибка ли двойное определение оператора возвращающий разный аргумент?

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Здравствуйте, является ли данное определение ошибкой в заголовочном файле:

```
Template<class T> 
class Matrix {
    // ...
    vector<T&>& operator[](int i){...}
    const vector<T&>& operator[](int i) const{...}

    T& operator[](int i){...}
    const T& operator[](int i) const{...}
}
```

Comment: @PavelParshin, нет, это не дубликат

Comment: похоже ответ тот же, невозможно перезагрузить функции с отличаемы только по возвращаемому типу. Верно ?

Comment: Речь о наличие одновременно всех 4ёх версий `operator[]`?

Comment: @Ilya.K., вы можете оставить одну из пар перегруженных операторов - компилятор может разделять `const` и не-`const` версии оператора. Но одновременно обе пары - нет, такое невозможно.

Comment: @PavelParshin, а вот в таком варианте действительно является дубликатом.

Comment: Благодарю, доброго дня